# Why does the default Object.toString() include the hashcode?

Tags: java

If you execute:

```
System.out.println(someObj.toString());
```

you probably see the output like

> someObjectClassname@hashcodenumber

My question : Is there any specific reason why hashCode number is displayed there?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The object hash code is the only *standard* identifier that might allow you to tell different arbitrary objects apart in Java. It's not necessarily unique, but equal objects normally have the same hash code.

The default `toString()` method shows the object class and its hash code so that you can hopefully tell different object instances apart. Since it is also used by default in error messages, this makes quite a bit of sense.

See the description of the [`hashCode()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry for asking you this, IS there any spec explaining about this?

Comment: Reading the javadoc comments on java.lang.Object explains at least parts of it.

Comment: Well, Its like we got to assume the reason why so. But there is no exact explanation isn't?

Comment: I believe the contract is that objects for which equal returns true MUST return the same hashcodes.

Answer (score 18):

***Adding something useful.***

Some newbies may be confused as to why the hascode value returned via `toString()`
is different than what is returned via `hashCode()`.
This is because the `toString()` method returns a hex representaion of the same hashcode .

`Integer.toHexString(object.hashCode());` will return the same value returned by `object.toString()`.

Answer (score 5):

From the [**javadocs**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> As much as is reasonably practical,
>   the `hashCode` method defined by class
>   Object does return distinct integers
>   for distinct objects. (This is
>   typically implemented by converting
>   the internal address of the object
>   into an integer, but this
>   implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming
>   language.)

The hashCode appears in the string representation of the object so that you can distinguish this object from other objects of the same class. This can be useful for debugging.

Comment: actually System.identityHashCode nowadays is using an assigned random number (since the address is far from 'stable')