# hashmap using a "employee class" as the value

Tags: java

I created a `HashMap` where the keys are `Integers` and the values are of the `Employee` class. `Employee` contains the employee's first name, last name and address. I am having issues with printing out the values. Here is what i tried.

```
employees.put(5, e1);

String test=employees.get(5).toString();
System.out.println(employees.toString());
System.out.println(test);
```

output:

```
{5=identitymanagement.Employee@6da264f1}
identitymanagement.Employee@6da264f1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing. Your first output is the hash (key 5, value identitymanagement.Employee@6da264f1), the second is the employee class identitymanagement.Employee@6da264f. What do you expect to see?

Comment: All is good, keep going!

Comment: Overwrite toString in employee if you want to be able to print it.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/java-object-default-tostring) question.

Comment: You're currently printing out the employee object, and the number that you're seeing is its reference in memory. You'll need to access that object's fields and print those.

Comment: You even did not give him a chance to phrase a question.. Not good, really.

Comment: What exactly do you want to print for the `Employee` class? `identitymanagement.Employee@6da264f1` is the default `toString()` method for any class. You need to either program a new `toString()`, or use a `java.util.Iterator` over the `keySet()` to print out the key and a custom representation of the `Employee` for each entry.

Answer (score 2):

**A look at your code**

```
String test=employees.get(5).toString();
```

This will grab the item with the key `5` in your hashmap, then call that object's `toString` method. The way your object is behaving at the moment implies you have no overridden that method, which is why it is printing out the objects address in memory.

```
System.out.println(employees.toString());
```

This will attempt to print out the `HashMap` object. In the same vain as your `Employee` class, HashMap does not override it's `toString` method, so it simply prints out the objects reference in memory.

**A solution**

The convention, when outputting the details of a class, is to override the `toString()` method. This would look something like this:

```
public String toString()
{
   return "name: " + name;
}
```

When you place this method in your class, you can call the `toString` method and it won't just print out the memory address of the object, which is what it is doing at the moment :)

When using this code, all you have to do is pass the object to the `System.out.println` method and it will do the rest:

```
Employee e = employees.get(5);
System.out.println(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is

```
Employee e = employees.get(5); // return's Employee object stored in map with key 5

String firstName = e.firstName;
String lastName = e.lastName;
String address = e.address;
```

Comment: I think overriding the `toString` method gives much cleaner code.