# get() method for HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to get a value with the key. I'm using get() method. My key is an object composed with int and String. So I make and object

```
HashMap<Keys,String> test = readFile(fileName2);
Keys myKey = new Keys(2,"SM");
test.get(myKey);
```

And I received null. When I look at debbuging mode or when I print keySet I received something like this

`[Keys@d9c6e2, Keys@10285d8, Keys@c3dd7e]`

although my key should be

`[1,"GM",  2,"SM",  3"PM"]`

why the key look like this `Keys@d9c6e2` instead of `2,"SM"?` and how to get the value with the key `2,"SM"`?

I override toString methid in Keys . It looks better but still i have null value and im sure there is some value.

```
    Keys myKey = new Keys(2,"GL-G--T");
    System.out.println(myKey.toString());
    System.out.println(test.get(myKey.toString()));
    Set keyset = test.keySet();
    System.out.println(keyset);


    2,GL-G--T
    null
    [3,PNSN--G, 2,GL-G--T, 1,SM]
```

Comment: Do you have a toString method on your keys? Looks like the java object reference is being shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* as you are doing use a special Keys object as the key to your hash map-- you then just need to correctly implement hashCode and equals on that Keys class as others have explained.

Unless you have a specific reason not to, though, you really could just use a String as the key to the hash map. Create some method such as the following:

```
private static String getHashMapKeyFor(int intKey, String stringKey) {
  return stringKey + "|" + intKey;
}
```

and declare your hash map as taking a String as the key type. Then, whenever you want to put/find a value in the hash map, call the above method first to get the actual key to use to the hash map.

Using the custom object class may have a superficial air of "correctness" or "engineeredness" to it, but in reality, just using a String will generally perform equally well and if anything may even save slightly on memory.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override toString method on your Keys object. Otherwise you will get the [default toString provided by java.lang.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4712139/217324).

You could implement the toString method to look something like this:

```
public class Keys {
    private final Integer i;
    private final String s;

    public Keys(Integer i, String s) {
        this.i = i;
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return i + "," + s;
    }
}
```

if you want the quotes to be displayed then you'd need to provide those:

```
return i + ",\"" + s + "\"";
```

You'll also need to [override the equals and hashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2265503/217324) for this object to be used as a key in a map:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Keys)) {
            return false;
        }
        Keys other = (Keys)o;
        return other.s.equals(s) && other.i.equals(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return toString().hashCode();
    }
```

If you don't override equals and hashcode, then the map uses the default implementations, which results in two Keys objects with the same values being unequal.

Comment: To be honest, though, this all ends up being overengineered for no tangible benefit. If the hashCode() method is simply concatenating the key elements into a string and then calling hashCode on that, I'd just do away with the special Keys object altogether and just use a concatenated string as the key to the hash map!

Comment: @Neil: I agree this particular example is overengineered. but this does show the OP how to get this object working with a map.

Comment: Sorry, yes I do agree-- it's a good answer per se. I think it's just worth mentioning that in the end there's a more straightforward solution to the overall problem!

Comment: I edit my class keys and i still have a problem with null value althogh i know there is a value - I see it in debug mode.

Comment: @Ewa: then add your toString method implementation to the question. without that there's nothing to say except your toString method is evidently broken.

Answer (score 0):

In your Keys.java object override the **toString** method. Currently it's using the method defined in java.lang.Object#toString

Comment: Actually, the solution to OP's problem is to override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. Mea culpa David

Comment: yes I've done it but still i have problem with null value - I edit my code and you can see what is printed