# Collections.max function is returning hashcodes (I think)

Tags: java, repast-simphony

I believe my Collections.max function is returning hash codes, but to be honest, I'm not entirely sure what is going on.

I am creating a list of trees with a random value of suitability, implementing a comparator, and then trying to find the highest suitability value (code is below).

```
public class Tree {
    public double suitability = Math.random();
    public int id;
    public static int count = 1;

    public Tree(double suitability, int id) {
        this.id = count;
        count++;    
    }

    public double getSuit() {
        return suitability;
    }

    public void setSuit(double suitability) {
        this.suitability = suitability;
    }

    public void measureSuit() {
           System.out.println("Tree number " + id + " has a suitability of " + suitability);
    }

}

class SuitComp implements Comparator<Tree> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Tree o1, Tree o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.getSuit(), o2.getSuit());
    }   
} 


public class EmeraldRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<Tree>();

        Tree tree;

        int treeCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < treeCount; i++) {
        tree = new Tree(i, i);

        trees.add(tree)

        Tree maxTree = Collections.max(trees, new SuitComp());

        System.out.println(maxTree);
        tree.measureSuit();

        }

    }

}
```

My output looks like this:

learnFromCave.Tree@60f32dde

Tree number 1 has a suitability of 0.6114866528786418

learnFromCave.Tree@60f32dde

Tree number 2 has a suitability of 0.28381422309266247

learnFromCave.Tree@3312b1dd

Tree number 3 has a suitability of 0.8441348268153896

learnFromCave.Tree@3312b1dd

Tree number 4 has a suitability of 0.6269071898386682

learnFromCave.Tree@3312b1dd

Tree number 5 has a suitability of 0.08717540188464434

learnFromCave.Tree@3312b1dd

Tree number 6 has a suitability of 0.3810530158434646

learnFromCave.Tree@3312b1dd

Tree number 7 has a suitability of 0.0938353693923476

learnFromCave.Tree@3312b1dd

Tree number 8 has a suitability of 0.3656868216321937

learnFromCave.Tree@105b3e5d

Tree number 9 has a suitability of 0.9717207037612301

learnFromCave.Tree@105b3e5d

Tree number 10 has a suitability of 0.44423960773823645

Comment: What's your question? Why do you get this output or how to get a readable String representation of your object? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/java-object-default-tostring and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734106/how-to-override-tostring-properly-in-java

Comment: You're printing a `Tree`, but you haven't implemented `toString` on it. What you're seeing is the default `toString()` implementation that Object gives you. You need to override `public String toString()` in Tree.

Comment: My question is why isn't it printing the max value of all the values in the list?

Comment: It is. The max value is an object of `Tree`, and when you try to print a `Tree`, you get what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println(maxTree);`calls `toString()` on `maxTree`. Since you did not override it, it calls the method on Object, which just outputs the full class name and some additional information.

You need to implement `toString()`yourself to get an more readable output.

```
public class Tree {
    public double suitability = Math.random();
    public int id;
    public static int count = 1;

    public Tree(double suitability, int id) {
        this.id = count;
        count++;
    }

    public double getSuit() {
        return suitability;
    }

    public void setSuit(double suitability) {
        this.suitability = suitability;
    }

    public void measureSuit() {
        System.out.println("Tree number " + id + " has a suitability of " + suitability);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I am the tree with id " + id;
    }
}
```