# How to convert object reference that are in string form to that refrence class object?

Tags: grails

String string = "org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@1c08114a";

// CommonsMultipartFile reference = string // Wrong

// Something like that.....

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you can't.  And more important: you shouldn't.  Don't call `toString()` on your object in the first place.  And if someone else hands you this down, beat them with a stick.

Long answer: the default `toString()` you are seeing there is just to make you differentiate objects.  the hashcode/address/pointer there would only allow reversing back to *a* object, if you either store them somewhere or you have the means to calculate it back (e.g. a Boolean could work (but don't even bother trying)). This is not C, where you could attempt to dash that number into an `void*` and hope the best.

Disclaimer: it might not be impossible to do, but if you have to do it, then there is something fundamental broken.  This answer intentionally does not answer the question.

For reference see [Why does the default Object.toString() include the hashcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode)

Comment: Ha, I now can't stop thinking about how you might retrieve an object reference from its hashcode....

Comment: You could probably use sun.misc.Unsafe