# Passing references in java

Tags: java, reference

I know for a fact that primitives are being passed by value in java.
But what are references being passed by? By reference, or by value? I can't find a clear answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: The first time you pass the object to a function, is by reference.  Inside this function, the reference becomes a "primitive" value, and it's passed by value to other functions.  The reference is like a pointer, and a pointer is an integer value.  The Java syntax hides this detail.

Comment: Are you confusing *reference* with *Hash Code*? [refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; **it passes them by value**.

**Example :**

```
public void swap(int var1, int var2)
{
  int temp = var1;
  var1 = var2;
  var2 = temp;
}
```

> When `swap()` returns, the variables passed as arguments will still
>   hold their original values.

In the case of object reference are passed by value hence it appears to be pass-by-reference **and This is not the case** !

**Example :**

```
public void swap(Point p1, Point p2)
{
  p1.x = 100;
  p1.y = 100;
  Point temp = p1;
  p1 = p2;
  p2 = temp;
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  Point pnt1 = new Point(0,0);
  Point pnt2 = new Point(0,0);
  System.out.println("X: " + pnt1.x + " Y: " +pnt1.y); 
  System.out.println("X: " + pnt2.x + " Y: " +pnt2.y);
  System.out.println(" ");
  swap(pnt1,pnt2);
  System.out.println("X: " + pnt1.x + " Y:" + pnt1.y); 
  System.out.println("X: " + pnt2.x + " Y: " +pnt2.y);  
}
```

**Output :**

```
X: 0 Y: 0
X: 0 Y: 0
X: 100 Y: 100
X: 0 Y: 0
```

Comment: But primitives are no objects.

Comment: @exception1 true but the OP states they "know for a fact that primitives are being passed by value in java" The question is about objects not primitives.

Comment: Why is the example using primitives? Yet you're talking about objects.

Comment: i updated my answer for primitives :)

Comment: But "I know for a fact that primitives are being passed by value in java" So, primitives is not their query.

Comment: i'm editing the answer this is why .. i edited part 1 one and now part 2 for objects :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, everything is passed by reference. Remember though that all objects in Java are stored as pointers.  When you pass an object, you are passing a reference to the pointer, no the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Source: Google

> Java passes all primitive data types by value. This means that a copy
>   is made, so that it cannot be modified. When passing Java objects,
>   you're passing an object reference, which makes it possible to modify
>   the object's member variables.

A very nice explanation:
[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)