# What is the output?

Tags: java, output, bluej

What is displayed by Line 1 Below?
BlueJ prints out A@18fea98, but I don't think this is correct. Please help, thank you.

```
class A{
  private int x;
  public A(){
    x=0;
  }
}

//test code in client program
A test = new A();
out.println(test);//LINE 1
```

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: It is correct - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode

Comment: "The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `out.println(obj)` will invoke the `toString` method on object test, which by default will return the HashBased memory location of the object on which `toString` is invoked.

In your scenario: **`A@18fea98`**

Which is expected output. If you need to print the value of the x attribute, you have following two options

1. Call the getter to get the value of the attribute
2. Override the `toString` method on A class to return the representation you want

For example:

```
    class A{
       private int x;
       public A() { 
         x = 0;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return "A:"+x;
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I override the toString method?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a sample implementation, the output will be "A:0" in the current case. Feel free to modify the toString implementation as needed. also if the answer satisfied, please do accept the answer so that others might find it helpful