# errors when using own implemented linked list

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list, comparator

I tried to use my own implemented LinkedList.

```
 public class LinkedList<O> {
       private Node<O> first,last;
       private int count;
       public LinkedList(){}

       public Node getfirst(){
        if(first==null) return null;
        else return first;
       }
       public Node getLast(){
        if(first==null) return null;
        else return last;
       }
    public int getSize(){
        return count;
    }
    public void addFirst(Object x){
        if(first==null)first=last=new Node(x);
        else{
            Node temp =new Node(x);
            temp.next=first;
            first=temp;
        }
        count++;
    }
    public void addLast(Object x){
        if(first==null)first=last=new Node(x);
        else{
            last.next= new Node(x);
            last=last.next;
        }
        count++;
    }
    public void add(Object x,int index){
        if(index==0)addFirst(x);
        else if(index>=getSize())addLast(x);
        else{
            Node current=first;
            for(int i=0; i<index-1;i++)
                current=current.next;
            Node temp = new Node(x);
            temp.next=current.next;
            current.next=temp;
            count++;
        }
    }
    public boolean removeFirst(){
        if(first==null)return false;
        else if(first==last){
            first=last=null;
            count--;
            return true;
            }
        else{
            first=first.next;
            count--;
            return true;
            }
    }
    public boolean removeLast(){
        if(first==null)return false;
        else if(first==last){
            first=last=null;
            count--;
            return true;
            }
        else{
            Node current=first;
            for(int i=0;i<getSize()-2;i++)
                current=current.next;
            last=current;
            last.next=null;
            count--;
            return true;
            }
    }
    public boolean remove(int index){
        if(index==0)return removeFirst();
        else if(index==getSize()-1)return removeLast();
        else{
            Node current=first;
            for(int i=0;i<index-1;i++)
                current=current.next;
            current.next=(current.next).next;
            count--;
            return true;
            }
    }
}




public class Node<E> {
   E element;
   Node<E> next;
   public Node(E element) {
      this.element = element;
    }
}
```

when I used :

```
 for(Book b:books){
        System.out.println(b);
 }
```

it gave me an error: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

So, I tried to use :

```
for(Book current=books.getFirst(); current !=null; current=current.next){
    System.out.println(current);
    }
```

It print :

```
project11.Node@139a55
project11.Node@1db9742
project11.Node@106d69c
```

and when I used collection.sort

```
Collections.sort(books,new Comparator<Book>()){
public int compare(Book book1, Book book2) {
    return book1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(book2.getTitle());
    }
    }
```

It gave me: The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (LinkedList, Stock.MyTitleComp)

Can someone explain these errors please and how to fix them.

Comment: its all worked out, but now it gives me   java.lang.NullPointerException at Collections.sort(books,new Comparator<Book>())

Comment: before using collections.sort it works just fine, there is no null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and third errors you are seeing is since you created a list of your own, but you did not implement the [List interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), so methods that work on lists (or Iterable, this one is a super-interface of List) does not work on it. Once you'll implement the interface, it will work

The second error is simply missing `toString()` implementation of your class, so you are getting this toString implementation from Object, which gives a not so readable print, override it with how you want your class to be printed

Answer (score 1):

For #1, it means what it says.  You can only use for-each loops over implementors of the `java.lang.Iterable` interface or arrays.

For #2, you're running into [Why does the default Object.toString() include the hashcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode).

For #3, your list still doesn't implement the `java.util.List` interface, so `Collections.sort` can't do anything with it for the same reason #1 didn't work.  You also messed up the parentheses, it seems.