# base64Binary in soap web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client, restlet, webservice-client

Application calling SOAP web services. One of the xml element is expecting data type as `base64Binary` like

```
<sessionPassword>base64Binary</sessionPassword>
```

1.I can read it while sax parsing like:

```
 setSessionPassword((new String(ch,start,length)).getBytes());
```

Is this correct?

2.I need to pass this password field to URI like this:

```
private static final String URI_BASE = "https://srini3000.com/Conversion/gateway.asmx/ASAPIDList?";   
String _sessionNum = "sessionNum=$1&";
String _sessionPaswrd = "sessionPassword=$2&sessionPassword=";

StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URI_BASE) ;
url.append(_sessionNum.replace("$1",Integer.toString(xmlHandler.getSessionNum())));
url.append(_sessionPaswrd.replace("$2",xmlHandler.getSessionPassword().toString()));
```

After making like in point2 I am facing Cannot convert [B@79be0360 to System.Byte.

Any suggestions please.
FYI I am using restlet to make the uri calls.
FYI XmlHandler is a pojo class, built after xml parsing. it has `SessionNum`, `SessionPassword` (declared as `byte[]`) fields.

Answer (score 1):

About your first question, depends on the bean representation of your `xsd`.  There are some engines which internally encode\decode to *base64* when `set`\ `get` method is invoked for fields of *base64Binary* type, but there are another ones which not perform this for you. So depends on implementation could be necessary to encode the `password` before invoke `setSessionPassword()`.

About your second question, if `sessionPassword` is declared as follows inside your *POJO*:

```
public class yourPojo {
   private byte[] sessionPassword;
   ...
   public byte[] getSessionPassword(){
       return sessionPassword;
   }
}
```

Then the follow line is not working as you expect:

```
xmlHandler.getSessionPassword().toString()
```

Because `byte` type not override `toString()` method, so `getSessionPassword().toString()` is returning `[B@79be0360` which is not the correct value (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode) to more info about default `toString()` behavior).

To solve your problem you've to use the follow code instead of invoke `toString()`:

```
_sessionPaswrd.replace("$2",new String(xmlHandler.getSessionPassword(),"UTF-8"));
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: By the way really great thought about "There are some engines which internally encode\decode to base64" cause in my case I did it "twice" on my side and then inside jax-ws impl automatically. Thanks again!

Comment: nice that this explanation helps you @DzmitryHubin :)