# Unable to display object array using get(index)

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to display the different objects in an ArrayList. In my project context, one student is one object.

I used an ArrayList to store all the different student objects and I am having problems reading the ArrayList.

```
 <%
   String student_name = request.getParameter("studentName"); 
  ArrayList<Object[]> studentList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
  if(student_name != null && student_name.length() > 0) {
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from      users where firstname LIKE ? ");
  preparedStatement.setString(1, "%" +student_name+ "%");
  ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

  while (resultSet.next()) {
      String first_name = resultSet.getString("firstname");
      String last_name = resultSet.getString("lastname");
      String email = resultSet.getString("email");

      Object[] student = {first_name,last_name,email};
      studentList.add(student);
      session.setAttribute("studentObject",studentList);


      //System.out.println("First Name: " + first_name + "," + "Last Name: " + last_name);
      System.out.println(studentList.get(0));


  }
```

When I try to display (studentList.get(0)), all I see is "[Ljava.lang.String;@XXXX"

How do i get it to display the different student objects based on the index ?

Comment: You got the student object. The output tells you that it is an array of strings at address XXXXX. To get the elements of the student object (e.g. first_name), you have to access the appropriate index: `System.out.println(studentList.get(0)[0]);`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You're just getting the result of the `Object[]`'s toString method, which is what you see.  What would you like?

Comment: Are you doing that inside JSP page?

Answer (score 1):

At first, It will be more idiomatic in Java to define your own class `Student`. Write an extractor to that class, define `toString` method and it will be great.

Java requires you to define `toString` method to any type of object that will be printed. So, you have to define `toString` for your `Student` class.

But you are using an array. `Java` doesn't have `toString` method defined for Arrays. So I would propose you to do something like this. (I'm a bit on rush so code may contain some mistakes:

```
// At first it could be better to define a structure
// that represents a student
// class must be defined in separate file like Student.java
// Student.java
public class Student {
   // constructor for the Student object
   public Student(final String firstName,
                  final String lastName,
                  final String email) {

       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName  = lastName;
       this.email     = email;
   }

   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String email;

   @override String toString() {
       return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + email;
   }

   // getters
   public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
   public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
   public String getEmail() { return email; }

   // setters
   public void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public void setLastName(final String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public void setEmail(final String email) {
       this.email = email;
   }
} // end of Student.java file
///////////////////////////////////////////

final ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

.... // your code

ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next()) {
   // creating a new student with new keyword
   final Student currentStudent = new Student(
       resultSet.getString("firstname"),
       resultSet.getString("lastname"),
       resultSet.getString("email")
   )

   // you are adding a student object to the list
   studentList.add(currentStudent);
   session.setAttribute("studentObject",studentList);

   // that should work
   // toString method will be called implicitly
   System.out.println(studentList.get(0));
}

// So you will have a list of students
// that will be accessable in the following manner:

studentList.get(0).getFirstName;
studentList.get(1).setFirstName("New name");
```

If you want a different behaviour you may call those fields directly, or modify
the behavior of `toString` method

Java also assumes that you're using camelCase notation, you may find in in the [style guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studentList.get(0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are printing out the Object[] which is not exactly human readable.  I would suggest creating a new class called Student.  Then have three member variables firstName, lastName, and email.  Also create a toString() method for this new class.  Then you can have an ArrayList of Students.  This should simplify everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not trying to display a `String` as you expect, you're trying to display an `array` of `Objects`.

You could try : `System.out.println(studentList.get(0)[0])`;

You'll have an idea

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

1. Implement an object corresponding to `Object[]` student: 
   In this class you may override Object's `toString()`, and implement it as to wish to present the data.
   NOTE: this is very relevant to you because when printing `studentList.get(0)` you actually print call Object's default `toString()` which returns the reference to the object.
   For more information regarding default `Object.toString()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode).
2. The simplestway is to use [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html): 
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studentList.get(0)));