# Java Error on returning with a toString function

Tags: java, class, printing, tostring

I'm fairly new to Java, only been programming for a couple months with it so far.

I have two classes, `TimeSlot` and `LabGroup`.

In the `TimeSlot` class there is the code--

```
private Time start;
private Time end;
private String day;

public TimeSlot(String spec) {
    //splits given string on each space
    String[] splitSpec = spec.split(" ");
    day = splitSpec[0];

    //uses the class Time, and passes in the hour and the minute of the time the lab begins.
    this.start = new Time(splitSpec[1]);

    //uses the class Time, and passes in the hour and the minute of the time the lab finishes.
    this.end = new Time(splitSpec[2]);  
}
```

Then in the `LabGroup` class there is the code--

```
public String charLabel;
public TimeSlot timeSpec;
public String lineTime;

public LabGroup(String line) {

    String[] lineSplit = line.split(" ");
    charLabel = lineSplit[0];

    //string a = "Day StartTime EndTime"
    String a = lineSplit[1] + " " + lineSplit[2] + " " + lineSplit[3];

    timeSpec = new TimeSlot(a);


}
```

along with a `toString` method--

```
public String toString() {
    return "Group "+ charLabel + timeSpec+ "\n";

}
```

An example input into the `LabGroup` would be `"A Mon 13:00 15:00"` and should then give the output, through the `toString`, of --

```
Group A Mon 13:00 - 15:00
Group B Mon 15:00 - 17:00
Group C Tue 13:00 - 15:00
Group D Tue 15:00 - 17:00
```

But instead i am getting--

```
Group AlabExam1.TimeSlot@3f0fbfe5
, Group BlabExam1.TimeSlot@ea0e8b8
, Group ClabExam1.TimeSlot@25eab2ba
, Group DlabExam1.TimeSlot@37528b33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `toString` method because if you print `charLabel` it will simply call the `toString` method in `Object` class which returns `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`

So, you need to do either of below:

1) implement `toString` method in `TimeSlot` like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return day + " " + start + " - " + end;
}
```

2) Modify `LabGroup` `toString` method like below by introducing getter methods in `TimeSlot`

```
public String toString() {
    return "Group " + charLabel.getDay() + " " + charLabel.getStart() + " - " + charLabel.getEnd();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided method toString() in class LabGroup - and this method works (with some minor issues). The problem is that you haven’t provided method toString() in class TimeSpec.

Answer (score 0):

when you do `return "Group "+ charLabel + timeSpec+ "\n";` You're telling the program to return your object timeSpec as a string.
 So basically it will call your TimeSlot toString function, which returns your `TimeSlot@3f0fbfe5` ([ClassName@HashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode)).
What you need to do is to [override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) TimeSlot's toString, so that when it is called it gives a string in a format you've chosen.
Hope it helps.