# how do you use a for-loop over an object array and return a string listing information of the objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, tostring

I have an array of objects and each of those objects has information for a specific person, how can I iterate over each object in that array and return their information in this toString()?

```
     @Override
 public String toString()
 {
     String tempString = " ";
      for(int i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++)
     {
         tempString = " All people currently residing on the stack: " +personArray[i];
     }


     return ""+tempString;
 }
```

I know do not need the array to do this, but I just wanted to know how to do it using a for-loop. I will continue to work on this, but I just want to know.

Comment: Why don't you just invoke `toString()`?

Comment: You're already doing it (in a strange, awkward, buggy and inefficient way, but that's another matter). Have you executed this code? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead? What is the concatenation operator in Java? All Java tutorials and books have that information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Comment: @AniketSahrawat he's already invoking toString(), implicitly.

Comment: What are you expecting to see as result?

Comment: @JBNizet I think he mean to invoke the method `toString()` of some object which is not visible in the code. I am not sure if he mean to invoke a toString of `personArray[i]`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat this method **is** the toString() method. the problem is precisely to implement it.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah right. I was just bit confused by the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are keep ovveriding the string inside `for` loop . You should attached one to another. Inshort concatenate your current result with previous results.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++)
     {
         tempString += " All people currently residing on the stack: " +personArray[i];
             --------^
     }
```

That way you can store the previous objects String notation and add the new result to it. In the end you can have a whole result in `tempString`.

The more readable and efficient way is to use a `StringBuilder`

```
   @Override
 public String toString()
 {
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for(int i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++)
     {
         builder.append(" All people currently residing on the stack: " +personArray[i]);
     }


     return builder.toString();
 }
```

Note that you must have implemented the toString method of Person class already otherwise you end up seeing [gibberish output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode) in your result.

Comment: Could also use `StringBuilder`, which may be the better solution if there's a large number of items in the array.