# what is the values with @number format in debug mode?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In debug mode in the android studio, every variable has a number with @ like this :

```
container  = {FrameLayout@831696387136}
```

I think this number is an address but I can't find this in R.java.
what's this number and where it is?
and in this case, I want to know where is the **container** refer to - can I know this with **FrameLayout@831696387136**?
Thanks.

[image: sample code]

Comment: Its hashcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode

Comment: also this question might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: This is the container id, Which was stored in R.java file, You don't need to create it, it is Automatically generated file which stores every Resources id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the container where your are inflating, you don't have to do anything there...

This is just the container Id. In this case you are inflating a Fragment and using this container to show your content.