# In Java, what does the / (i.e., forward slash) mean in object references like $Lambda$15/0x00000008000a9440@32e6e9c3)?

Tags: java, jvm, jshell

In JShell, if I do this:

```java
interface Foo { String foo(); }
(Foo) () -> "hi"
```

I get

```java
|  created interface Foo
$2 ==> $Lambda$15/0x00000008000a9440@32e6e9c3
```

From the research below, I know the following:

$Lambda = [an in-memory reference, as opposed to one persisted to disk by an anonymous inner class (AIC), to the generated bytecode](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/behind-the-scenes-how-do-lambda-expressions-really-work-in-java)

$15 = [an object reference to the AIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388840/java-compiled-classes-contain-dollar-signs/11388863#11388863)

@32e6e9c3 = [the sequential number of the object created--at least, in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624284/while-debugging-java-codes-what-does-mean-in-statements-like-instance789-or/50625530#50625530)

But what does the `/` (slash) indicate, as in `/0x00000008000a9440`?

Comment: You want to know the meaning of "/" or "/0x00000008000a9440"?

Comment: It's just how [hidden classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) are named.

Comment: Following your link, and some sublinks, I found the defineHiddenClass method, in MethodHandles.Lookup that says: "Class.getName() returns the string GN + "/" + <suffix>, even though this is not a valid binary class or interface name." Is that what you mean?

Comment: Note you don't need to follow any further links. The `Class#getName()` documentation linked by Johannes directly says: "_If the class or interface is hidden, then the result is a string of the form: N + '/' + <suffix> where N is the binary name indicated by the class file passed to Lookup::defineHiddenClass, and <suffix> is an unqualified name_".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Summary

`$Lambda$15/0x00000008000a9440` is the name of the created hidden class.

As it will be shown below, `0x00000008000a9440` is called a suffix.

The name of the class can be retrieved by calling the `java.lang.Class.getName()` method.
Therefore:

- For example, the same class names can be retrieved by a Java program (not through JShell).
- The question does not seem to be about JShell, but about the Java language and the Java Virtual Machine.

### Example program to show name of hidden class

#### `Program` class

```java
package info.brunov.stackoverflow.question72804142;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public final class Program {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        printRuntimeInformation();

        final Supplier<String> supplier1 = () -> "";
        final Supplier<String> supplier2 = () -> "";
        final Supplier<String> supplier3 = () -> "";
        System.out.println(
            String.format("Supplier 1: %s", supplier1.getClass().getName())
        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format("Supplier 2: %s", supplier2.getClass().getName())
        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format("Supplier 3: %s", supplier3.getClass().getName())
        );
    }

    private static void printRuntimeInformation() {
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "Java Virtual Machine specification name: %s",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.name")
            )
        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "Java Virtual Machine specification version: %s",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.version")
            )
        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "Java Virtual Machine specification vendor: %s",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.specification.vendor")
            )
        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "Java Virtual Machine implementation name: %s",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.name")
            )
        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "Java Virtual Machine implementation version: %s",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.version")
            )
        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor: %s",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.vendor")
            )
        );
    }
}
```

#### Program output

```
Java Virtual Machine specification name: Java Virtual Machine Specification
Java Virtual Machine specification version: 18
Java Virtual Machine specification vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java Virtual Machine implementation name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
Java Virtual Machine implementation version: 18.0.1-ea+10-Debian-1
Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor: Debian
Supplier 1: info.brunov.stackoverflow.question72804142.Program$$Lambda$18/0x0000000800c031f0
Supplier 2: info.brunov.stackoverflow.question72804142.Program$$Lambda$19/0x0000000800c033f8
Supplier 3: info.brunov.stackoverflow.question72804142.Program$$Lambda$20/0x0000000800c03600
```

## Documentation references

### JEP 371: Hidden Classes

The hidden classes have been introduced since JDK 15.
For additional details, please, refer to the JEP: [JEP 371: Hidden Classes](https://openjdk.org/jeps/371).

Here is an excerpt from the JEP on the hidden class names:

> The major difference in how a hidden class is created lies in the name it is given. **A hidden class is not anonymous.** It has a name that is available via `Class::getName` and may be shown in diagnostics (such as the output of `java -verbose:class`), in JVM TI class loading events, in JFR events, and in stack traces. However, the name has a sufficiently unusual form that it effectively makes the class invisible to all other classes. The name is the concatenation of:
>
> 1. The binary name in internal form (JVMS 4.2.1) specified by `this_class` in the `ClassFile` structure, say `A/B/C`;
> 2. The `'.'` character; and
> 3. An unqualified name (JVMS 4.2.2) that is chosen by the JVM implementation.
>
> For example, if `this_class` specifies `com/example/Foo` (the internal form of the binary name `com.example.Foo`), then a hidden class derived from the `ClassFile` structure may be named `com/example/Foo.1234`. This string is neither a binary name nor the internal form of a binary name.
>
> Given a hidden class whose name is `A/B/C.x`, the result of `Class::getName` is the concatenation of:
>
> 1. The binary name `A.B.C` (obtained by taking `A/B/C` and replacing each `'/'` with `'.'`);
> 2. The '/' character; and
> 3. The unqualified name `x`.
>
> For example, if a hidden class is named `com/example/Foo.1234`, then the result of `Class::getName` is `com.example.Foo/1234`. Again, this string is neither a binary name nor the internal form of a binary name.
>
> The namespace of hidden classes is disjoint from the namespace of normal classes. Given a `ClassFile` structure where `this_class` specifies `com/example/Foo/1234`, invoking `cl.defineClass("com.example.Foo.1234", bytes, ...)` merely results in a normal class named `com.example.Foo.1234`, distinct from the hidden class named `com.example.Foo/1234`. It is impossible to create a normal class named `com.example.Foo/1234` because `cl.defineClass("com.example.Foo/1234", bytes, ...)` will reject the string argument as being not a binary name.

### Javadoc: `java.lang.Class#getName()` method

Let's refer to the method documentation: [Class (Java SE 15 & JDK 15)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

An excerpt from the documentation:

> public [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) getName()
>
> Returns the name of the entity (class, interface, array class, primitive type, or void) represented by this `Class` object.
>
> If this `Class` object represents a class or interface, not an array class, then:
>
> - If the class or interface is not [hidden](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isHidden()), then the [binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#binary-name) of the class or interface is returned.
> - If the class or interface is hidden, then the result is a string of the form: `N + '/' + <suffix>` where `N` is the [binary name](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#binary-name) indicated by the `class` file passed to [`Lookup::defineHiddenClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineHiddenClass(byte%5B%5D,boolean,java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup.ClassOption...)), and `<suffix>` is an unqualified name.

## Implementation details: OpenJDK Java Virtual Machine: Hidden class name

### Introduction

Let's consider the source code of OpenJDK 18.

Let's refer to the tag: [openjdk/jdk18 at jdk-18+37](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk18/tree/jdk-18%2B37).

Please, note that:

- The below execution paths are theoretical: I am using the mentioned source code tag.
- The below call stacks are real: I am using OpenJDK `18.0.1-ea+10-Debian-1`.

### Hidden class name mangling

Hidden class creation (the `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup.defineHiddenClass()` method) includes the mangling of its name.

Let's consider the following call stack:

```
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2346)
      at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:2432)
      at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup$ClassDefiner.defineClassAsLookup(MethodHandles.java:2413)
      at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineHiddenClass(MethodHandles.java:2119)
      at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.generateInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:385)
      at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:293)
      at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:228)
      at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:341)
      at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(DirectMethodHandle$Holder:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.invokeExact_MT(Invokers$Holder:-1)
      at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:134)
      at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:315)
      at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:279)
      at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:269)
      at info.brunov.stackoverflow.question72804142.Program.main(Program.java:9)
```

Then let's consider the following execution path as **the continuation of the call stack**:

```
Class<?> java.lang.ClassLoader#defineClass0(ClassLoader loader, Class<?> lookup, String name, byte[] b, int off, int len, ProtectionDomain pd, boolean initialize, int flags, Object classData)

// Native calls below.
jclass Unsafe_DefineClass0(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jstring name, jbyteArray data, int offset, int length, jobject loader, jobject pd)
jclass Unsafe_DefineClass_impl(JNIEnv *env, jstring name, jbyteArray data, int offset, int length, jobject loader, jobject pd)
JNIEXPORT jclass JNICALL
jclass JVM_DefineClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name, jobject loader, const jbyte *buf, jsize len, jobject pd)
jclass jvm_define_class_common(const char *name, jobject loader, const jbyte *buf, jsize len, jobject pd, const char *source, TRAPS)
InstanceKlass* SystemDictionary::resolve_from_stream(ClassFileStream* st, Symbol* class_name, Handle class_loader, const ClassLoadInfo& cl_info, TRAPS)
InstanceKlass* SystemDictionary::resolve_hidden_class_from_stream(ClassFileStream* st, Symbol* class_name, Handle class_loader, const ClassLoadInfo& cl_info, TRAPS)
InstanceKlass* KlassFactory::create_from_stream(ClassFileStream* stream, Symbol* name, ClassLoaderData* loader_data, const ClassLoadInfo& cl_info, TRAPS)
InstanceKlass* ClassFileParser::create_instance_klass(bool changed_by_loadhook, const ClassInstanceInfo& cl_inst_info, TRAPS)
void ClassFileParser::mangle_hidden_class_name(InstanceKlass* const ik)
```

Let's refer to the piece of source code: [jdk18/classFileParser.cpp at jdk-18+37 · openjdk/jdk18](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk18/blob/jdk-18+37/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#L5920-L5938):

```
void ClassFileParser::mangle_hidden_class_name(InstanceKlass* const ik) {
  ResourceMark rm;
  // Construct hidden name from _class_name, "+", and &ik. Note that we can't
  // use a '/' because that confuses finding the class's package.  Also, can't
  // use an illegal char such as ';' because that causes serialization issues
  // and issues with hidden classes that create their own hidden classes.
  char addr_buf[20];
  if (DumpSharedSpaces) {
    // We want stable names for the archived hidden classes (only for static
    // archive for now). Spaces under default_SharedBaseAddress() will be
    // occupied by the archive at run time, so we know that no dynamically
    // loaded InstanceKlass will be placed under there.
    static volatile size_t counter = 0;
    Atomic::cmpxchg(&counter, (size_t)0, Arguments::default_SharedBaseAddress()); // initialize it
    size_t new_id = Atomic::add(&counter, (size_t)1);
    jio_snprintf(addr_buf, 20, SIZE_FORMAT_HEX, new_id);
  } else {
    jio_snprintf(addr_buf, 20, INTPTR_FORMAT, p2i(ik));
  }
```

Please, note that the `+` character is used as the separator.

### Get hidden class name

The `java.lang.Class#getName()` method includes the character replacement: `+` is replaced with `/`.

Let's consider the following execution path:

```
String java.lang.Class.getName()
String java.lang.Class.initClassName()

// Native calls below.
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL JVM_InitClassName(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
oop java_lang_Class::name(Handle java_class, TRAPS)
const char* java_lang_Class::as_external_name(oop java_class)
const char* Klass::external_name() const
static char* convert_hidden_name_to_java(Symbol* name)
```

Let's refer to the piece of source code: [jdk18/klass.cpp at jdk-18+37 · openjdk/jdk18](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk18/blob/jdk-18%2B37/src/hotspot/share/oops/klass.cpp#L665-L666):

```
// Replace the last '+' char with '/'.
static char* convert_hidden_name_to_java(Symbol* name) {
```