# Why can't lambda class load?

Tags: java, class, lambda, classnotfoundexception

Why do I get an exception when I run the following code?
I went to the source code and found that this class was generated by ASM. Isn't the class generated in this way in the method area?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<? extends Runnable> runClass = test().getClass();
        ClassLoader classLoader = runClass.getClassLoader();

        System.out.println(classLoader.loadClass(Main.class.getName()));
        System.out.println(classLoader.loadClass(runClass.getName()));
    }

    public static Runnable test() {
        return () -> {};
    }
}
```

results

```
class link.yxw.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: link.yxw.Main$$Lambda$1/1324119927
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at link.yxw.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is: because the lambda class is hidden ([JEP 371 in JDK15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/371) standardized it and exposed an API, but it's been present since JDK 7) and cannot be accessed by other classes. You can find more information in blogposts and articles like [this one](https://foojay.io/today/what-are-hidden-classes-in-java-15/).

---

If we define:

```java
public static Runnable lambdaTest() {
    return () -> {
    };
}

public static Runnable anonymTest() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };
}
```

and run:

```java
System.out.println(Main.class.isHidden());
System.out.println(anonymTest().getClass().isHidden());
System.out.println(lambdaTest().getClass().isHidden());
```

we'll get:

```bash
false
false
true
```

---

If we print the name of the lambda class, we'll get different results on different JDK, but both boiling down to the same concept:

```
JDK 8-10: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main$$Lambda$1/791452441
JDK 11+:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800060840
```

[Class#getName() JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()) says:

> If the class or interface is hidden, then the result is a string of the form: N + '/' + <suffix> where N is the binary name indicated by the class file passed to Lookup::defineHiddenClass, and  is an unqualified name.

If you wanted to see the implementation: native JDK code for JDK 9 [can be found here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk9/blob/f00b63d24697cce8067f468fe6cd8510374a46f5/hotspot/src/share/vm/oops/klass.cpp#L575-L586) ([here's a short description of mirror classes](https://programming.vip/docs/diagram-class-loading.html)) and [here's the JDK 18 code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk18/blob/jdk-18+37/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#L5920-L5938) (been there since 15). If you want to read more, I recommend [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72738837/in-java-what-does-the-i-e-forward-slash-mean-in-object-references-like-l).

---

Finally let's see the `ClassLoader` code that looks up the class for loading:

```java
protected final Class<?> findLoadedClass(String name) {
    if (!checkName(name))
        return null;
    return findLoadedClass0(name);
}

// true if the name is null or has the potential to be a valid binary name
private static boolean checkName(String name) {
    if ((name == null) || (name.isEmpty()))
        return true;
    if ((name.indexOf('/') != -1) || (name.charAt(0) == '['))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

If the class name contains a `/` char, it's resolved as not a valid binary name and cannot be loaded. If you wondered about the `[` char - it marks an array class.