# I am getting the reference as output. What should i include in my program to get the output

Tags: java, arrays

```
package basicprograms;

public class Progrm {
    public long[] ph;
    public Progrm(long[] ph){
        this.ph=ph;
    }
}
```

The main method:

```
package basicprograms;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UseProgrm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Progrm> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        Progrm p1 = new Progrm(new long[] { 942758427l, 4298578432l, 3425962l });
        Progrm p2 = new Progrm(new long[] { 942758427l, 4298578432l, 3425962l });
        Progrm p3 = new Progrm(new long[] { 942758427l, 4298578432l, 3425962l });
        ar.add(p1);
        ar.add(p2);
        ar.add(p3);
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(ar.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Extend toString() method in Progrm class.

Comment: You want something like `System.out.println(ar.get(i)[0]); System.out.println(ar.get(i)[1]); System.out.println(ar.get(i)[2]);`, although overriding toString() would be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

By default, all classes in Java inherit from the `Object` class. In this case what you are actually printing is `Progrm::toString` method that is inherited for the `Object` class and by default is returning the hash. If you would like to print the content of the array(*public member ph* of the `Progrm` class) then you should override the `toString` of `Progrm` as follows:

```
public class Progrm {

    public long[] ph;

    public Progrm(long[] ph) {
        this.ph=ph;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Progrm{" +
            "ph=" + Arrays.toString(ph) +
            '}';
    }
}
```

and the output will be:

```
Progrm{ph=[942758427, 4298578432, 3425962]} 
Progrm{ph=[942758427, 4298578432, 3425962]}
Progrm{ph=[942758427, 4298578432, 3425962]}
```

For more info on `Object::toString`, you can refer to :
[Why does the default Object.toString() include the hashcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode)

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `toString()` method in your `Program` class

now, the `System.out.println` statements are calling the default implementation of the Object class.

Add this to your `Program` class:

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("");
  for ( long p : ph) {
    b.append("Value: " + p + ", ");
  }
  return b.toString();
}
```

Afterwards, you can modify it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < ar.get(i).ph.length; j++)
          System.out.println(ar.get(i).ph[j]);
 }
```

Comment: Are the *`* symbols there because of a bad slack habits ? :)

Comment: Is it better now? ;)