# Spring boot CrudRepository saves bad data

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, derby

i have problem with saving data in DB.I'm new in Spring Boot. When i run my program the result of writen data is: packagename@randomcode example:**com.abc.patient.Patient@6e3e681e**

This is my Entity class - Patient.java

```
@Entity
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // getter, setter, constructor, etc
}
```

This is my CrudRepo PatientRepository.java

```
public interface PatientRepository extends CrudRepository<Patient,Integer> {
}
```

This is my Service class PatientService.java

```
@Service
public class PatientService {

    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientRepository;

    public void savePatient (String name) {
        Patient patient = new Patient(name);
        patientRepository.save(patient);
    }

    public Optional<Patient> showPatient(int id) {
        return patientRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Patient> showAllPatients() {
        List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();
        patientRepository.findAll().forEach(patients::add);
        return patients;
    }
}
```

I think that problem in in the `savePatient` method in this line:

```
Patient patients = new Patient(name);
```

I checked the `"name"` parameter and it's in 100% correct String. I'm using Derby DB.

Comment: There is no constructor define for this line  Patient patients = new Patient(name) in Patient class entity.

Comment: I think that is just because you haven't provided a toString method for your Patients class... the default toString just prints out the name of the class and the memory address. Did you actually inspect it in a debugger?

Comment: Maybe you should override `Patient`'s `to_string` method?

Comment: YESSS ! thank You  AHungerArtis and Laurenz-Albe ! The problem was in Patient class.I haven't provide toString method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem you have is how you are printing out your `Patient` class. Define a proper `toString()` or just debug yourself to see the resulting fields. There is no problem in your JPA implementation.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode) for the details of default `toString`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public void savePatient(Patient patient) {
    patientRepository.save(patient);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.The problem was in Patient class.I haven't provide toString method.