# String values in Optional ofNullable

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Imagine an `Optional.ofNullable` check assigning to a `String`:

```
String result = Optional.ofNullable(class1)
                .map(Class1::getClass2)
                .map(Class2::getResult);
```

Where `getResult` returns a `String`.

While I know this doesn't compile, I can fix it by either adding `toString()` or `.orElse("");` to sort that.

As it stands, the error is:

> Bad return type in method reference, cannot convert java.lang.String
>   to U

I understand adding `orElse("")` as that will assign `result` to an empty `String`.

But what's the benefit of adding `toString()` if something is `null` along the way? Or is that just to purely get it to compile?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question entirely. But the `Optional` class is designed for either contain a value or not, and is often used as alternative to `null`. The `map` method does not return a `String` (for if it did, the returning value could be `null`), but instead returns an `Optional` containing the new value. In order to get the result, you could call `get()`, which also returns the resulting string, but could also throw a `NoSuchElementException`. To return either the resulting value or a fallback value, you have to call `orElse(fallbackValue)`.

Comment: `toString` returns a representation of the Optional not of the contained value, if any.

Comment: @MCEmperor Is there a way to call `get()` and also call `orElse()` in the same chain?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks - I understand that now and it seems `get()` is what I want. But to combine with an `orElse()` clause in case it doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `map` is `Optional <U>`, so to get a real value you should call for `orElse` with the return type of `T`.

This is the `toString` implementation if the `Optional`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return value != null
        ? String.format("Optional[%s]", value)
        : "Optional.empty";
}
```

So, calling `toString` you'll never get the real value, but a value wrapped to `Optional`, while `orElse` will return you the default provided value.

Let's see the difference:

```
Integer i = 4;
String s = Optional.ofNullable(i)
         .map(Objects::toString)
         .toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
Optional[4]
```

With `null`:

```
Integer i = null;
String s = Optional.ofNullable(i)
          .map(Objects::toString)
          .toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
Optional.empty
```

While using `orElse`:

```
Integer i = null;
String s = Optional.ofNullable(i)
        .map(Objects::toString)
        .orElse("None");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
None
```

So you can see that there are different purposes of these methods.

And the answer to your comment:

"**Is there a way to call get() and also call orElse() in the same chain?**"

```
Integer i = 10;
String s = Optional.ofNullable(i)
        .map(Objects::toString)
        .orElse("None");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
10
```

You don't need to call `get` explicitly, the value will be fetched if not `null`;

```
/**
 * If a value is present, returns the value, otherwise returns
 * {@code other}.
 *
 * @param other the value to be returned, if no value is present.
 *        May be {@code null}.
 * @return the value, if present, otherwise {@code other}
 */
public T orElse(T other) {
    return value != null ? value : other;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `result` to be null if something along the way returns null then do `orElse(null)`

```
String result = Optional.ofNullable(class1)
            .map(Class1::getClass2)
            .map(Class2::getResult).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I understand adding orElse("") as that will assign result to an empty
>   String.

It doesn't sound like you do understand it to me because that's not a good description of what's happening. `Optional.orElse` does the following: if the optional contains a value, return that value. If it doesn't contain a value, return whatever argument you've given it.

It's semantically equivalent to the following:

```
if (optional.ifPresent())
{
    return optional.get();
}
else
{
    return theArgument;
}
```

Calling `toString`, while it will satisfy the compiler, is **not** what you want to do. You are converting the `Optional` object *itself* to a String, not getting the String from inside! While your string will be *included*, this is only because of how the JDK developers have decided to implement `toString`. They could equally have not provided an implementation, leaving you with [just the default behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode).

Calling `toString` on an `Optional`  should basically never be relied upon outside of logging. It's essentially just debugging information. If you do this, then information about the `Optional` wrapper will be printed as well, which is almost certainly not what you want.

```
System.out.println(Optional.empty());   // Optional.empty
System.out.println(Optional.of("foo")); // Optional[foo]
```