# Getting of pointer value when setText should be string in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get string values from Db like below:

```
List<Workout> workouts = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWorkoutDao().getAll();

txtShowWorkout.setText(workouts.get(0).toString());
```

However, it going to give output like that:
I would like to get string value but it is writing pointer values.

`com.example.fitnessapp.context.Workout@78db232`
`com.example.fitnessapp.context.Workout@d2b4056`

Also my getAll() function is below:

```
 @Override
  public List<Workout> getAll() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM Workout";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
    try {
      final int _cursorIndexOfİd = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "id");
      final int _cursorIndexOfWorkoutName = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "workout_name");
      final int _cursorIndexOfFocusArea = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "focus_area");
      final int _cursorIndexOfEquipment = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "Equipment");
      final int _cursorIndexOfReps = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "reps");
      final int _cursorIndexOfDate = CursorUtil.getColumnIndexOrThrow(_cursor, "date");
      final List<Workout> _result = new ArrayList<Workout>(_cursor.getCount());
      while(_cursor.moveToNext()) {
        final Workout _item;
        _item = new Workout();
        _item.id = (int) _cursor.getInt(_cursorIndexOfİd);
        _item.workout_name = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfWorkoutName);
        _item.focus_area = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfFocusArea);
        _item.Equipment = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfEquipment);
        _item.reps = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfReps);
        _item.date = _cursor.getString(_cursorIndexOfDate);
        _result.add(_item);
      }
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
      _statement.release();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You print `List<Workout>` which is returned by getAll() instead of a String

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you give some more details? thanks @Zain

Comment: `workouts` object is `List<Workout>` and hence `workouts.get(0)` is a `Workout` not a String.. so you need a way to convert it to a String.. Can you share `Workout` class?

Comment: You can override `toString()` within the `Workout` class and adjust the returned value to what you want to show in `txtShowWorkout.setText(workouts.get(0).toString())`

Comment: Workout class, please check it. @Zain
```
@Entity
public class Workout {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo
    public String workout_name;

    @ColumnInfo
    public String focus_area;

    @ColumnInfo
    public String Equipment;

    @ColumnInfo
    public String reps;

    @ColumnInfo
    public String date;
}
```

Comment: I think you need the workout_name, so txtShowWorkout.setText(workouts.get(0).workout_name

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the `Workout` object's [default string representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode). Assuming you want to print the workout name, you would change

```
txtShowWorkout.setText(workouts.get(0).toString());
```

to

```
txtShowWorkout.setText(workouts.get(0).workout_name);
```

If you want to print something other than the name, you can either override `toString()` on the Workout class to print what you want, or make a method like

```
String workoutTitle(Workout w) {
    // make the string you want to show
    return w.workout_name + " (" + w.focus_area + ")";
}
```

then use

```
txtShowWorkout.setText(workoutTitle(workouts.get(0)));
```