# Why if i try to print an object i get the name of the class followed by a hexadezimal representation?

Tags: java, object

```
 MyClass mcc1d = new MyClass(18, "hello");
 System.out.println(mcc1a);
```

Why is the following the output of the code above?

```
MyClass@23fc625e
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the default Object.toString() include the hashcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in Java, `System.out.println()` applied on an object calls `.toString()`. The default of the `.toString()`-method returns the class name followed by `@` followed by the hash representation of the object.

Comment: Let's not narrow it with `System.out.println(` method. Maybe this expression is more suitable: Any object can be converted to String in Java using `.toString()` method inherited by the Object class. By default, their Class Name and Hashcode are returned in this method. Therefore, you should override it and return whatever you want.

Comment: How did I narrow it down?

Comment: not only `println()` method calls toString method. Instead, any conversion from an Object to String is done this way.

Comment: Yes. However, the question asked why `println()` specifically behaves this way