# Why foreach loop gives array elements but for loop gives address instead of elements? In java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I tried to print all the elements in an array using both for loop and foreach loop.

In for loop, I got addresses of elements instead of elements themselves. But by using for loop I got the elements themselves. So how this is working even I didn't override toString method also but am getting elements!!

```
public class ArrayReturn {
    public static int[] Multi(int []a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = a[i]*2;
        }
        return a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ar[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7};
        int z[] = Multi(ar);
        for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(z);
        }
        for (int i : z) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        
    }
}
OUTPUT
[I@5a07e868
[I@5a07e868
[I@5a07e868
[I@5a07e868
[I@5a07e868
[I@5a07e868
4
6
8
10
12
14
```

I expected either address from both loops or elements. But I got address in for loop and elements in foreach loop.

Comment: "In for loop, I got addresses of elements instead of elements themselves." - **No**; you got **some numbers**, which happen to be the ones you can use to **index** the array. "I expected either address from both loops or elements." I can't understand why. If they did the same thing, what would be the point of putting both of them into the language?

Comment: In your `for` loop you are just printing `z` each iteration, which has nothing to do with the loop.

Comment: "So how this is working even I didn't override toString method also but am getting elements!!" The elements of the array **are integers**, so they would look the same way as what you get from the other loop - just with different values. The weird `[I@5a07e868` things that you see printed have **nothing to do with** "elements" (and "element" is not a type; it just means "one of the things that is in the array); that is the text that Java uses to display **the array**. It does that because the code says `System.out.println(z);`, and `z` means **the array**.

Comment: In Java, an array is a reference type. The line  `System.out.println(z);` uses the [default `toString` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), inherited from `Object`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have told you, in your for loop you're printing the array z, so for that reason it's printing <del>the object address</del> what you're seeing. If you want to print the value stored in each position, you have to use the for loop's index.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(z[i]);
    }
```